# Error while deliver app to app store via Application loader

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I sending ios libgdx robovm app (ipa) to App Store via Application Loader and getting this error:

> Error ITMS-90034 "Missing or invalid signature. bundle
>   'com.apple.LLDB.framework' at bundle path
>   'Payload/IOSLauncher/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework' is not signed using an
>   Apple submission certificate."

When I trying to send test robovm application (robovm-game-app-master at https://github.com/robovm/robovm-game-app), there is no problem.
I thought that incorrect config file (gradle, robovm.xml, info.plist.xml or etc) is problem, but I set all config files similar in these both apps. 
When I compiling my app, I getting these log messages:

> [INFO] Copying resource /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/lldb-defines.h
>   to
>   /Users/rustam/Desktop/IOSLauncher.app/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers
>   [INFO] Copying resource /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/lldb-enumerations.h
>   to
>   /Users/rustam/Desktop/IOSLauncher.app/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers
>   [INFO] Copying resource /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/bin/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers/lldb-forward.h
>   to
>   /Users/rustam/Desktop/IOSLauncher.app/lldb/mac/LLDB.framework/Headers
>   ...

When I compiling test robovm app, I not getting messages like this,
I not getting messages about LLDB and I don't know what is it.
Output ipa filesize is too big - 80mb (apk - 7mb). It also contains strange folders "mac", "android".
Help me please

Comment: That framework being copied looks like an OSX framework, not an iOS framework.

Comment: How can I remove it?